# WPF MVVM: How to load views "on demand" without using plug-in architecture?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have an Outlook-like WPF UI with navigation on the left, a toolbar on top, and a status bar at the bottom, all within a `DockPanel`.

The "main" area of the application is within a `DataGrid` wich is the LastChild and therefore fills the remaining space and it currently looks like this:

```
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <views:View1 Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <views:View2 Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <views:View3 Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <views:View4 Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
</Grid>
```

These views are all user controls that have their own ViewModels with `Visibility` property bound to a property in its ViewModel and controlled by the navigation pane selections. When a navigation pane item is selected the main ViewModel sends a message to ViewModels of the views and upon receiving the message the ViewModels of the views set their `Visibility` properties accordingly...

Now, this works fine but doesn't feel right since all the ViewModels of these views are being instantiated on the app start instead of when the related navigation pane is selected bringing up questions about performance and memory usage...

My question is if there is a way of loading each view and its ViewModel "on demand", when the related navigation pane is selected and unloading these views and ViewModels when a different navigation pane is selected without resorting to PRISM/MEF or some other plugin architecture... and, more general how would you approach building an application like this with multiple views/ViewModels "embedded" within the main view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I do:

First, on your main ViewModel (the one that's servicing the main window), add a Content property:

```
object _content;
public object Content
{
    get { return _content; }
    set
    {
        _content = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Content");
    }
}
```

When the user switches from view to view, set the `Content` property to the appropriate ViewModel for that view they've selected.

In the main window, then, you can display the current Content ViewModel using a ContentControl:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}" />
```

... and somewhere above that, define a DataTemplate for each of the various ViewModels that `Content` might be set to:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FooViewModel}">
    <my:FooUserControl />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BarViewModel}">
    <my:BarUserControl />
</DataTemplate>
```

So now the ContentControl will be responsible for initializing and displaying each of your UserControls depending on which ViewModel is currently "active".

Comment: You might also be interested in my MVVM Light contrib project which includes a ScreenConductor class: http://matthamilton.net/madprops-mvvmlight-screenconductor

Comment: Check out Caliburn Micro also, in particular screens and conductors.

Comment: @Derek agreed - I'm an MVVM Light guy but CM does a lot of this for you.

Comment: @kzen If you want a complete "sample" application that uses this technique, check out https://bitbucket.org/mabster/comicster

Comment: It appears there is one remaining issue... when the `Content` is set to another ViewModel the previous ViewModel doesn't go out of scope, it remains in memory... any idea how to dispose of it because `Content = null` prior to assigning the new ViewModel doesn't do the trick?

Comment: This also results in multiple copies of the same ViewModel being instantiated... one copy for each time you set the `Content` to that same ViewModel...

Comment: @kzen (re: instantiating multiple copies) Not necessarily. You could keep the "content" ViewModels around as private fields. Disposing a ViewModel shouldn't be a high priority since they're usually very lightweight compared to the views themselves.

Comment: @Matt, yes thanks, keeping around `Content` ViewModels as private fields takes care of the multiple copies... I'm still trying to find a way to dispose of the `Content` ViewModels as needed since sometimes I don't want them to receive messages from other ViewModels if they are not the 'current' `Content` ViewModel... I can solve this by having a `public bool ProcessMessages { get; set; }` property in these ViewModels in order to stop them from processing these messages but it 'feels' suboptimal...

Comment: In that scenario I make sure my `Content` ViewModels all implement, say, IContentViewModel, and give that interface a couple of methods to call as the object is activated/deactivated. Perhaps an OnShow and OnHide method. Then the VMs can decide what to do as they become active.